# Unexpected behavior S/H and ADC simulation

Tags: adc, simulation, converter, kicad, sample-and-hold

I am trying to simulate a primitive ADC consisting of sample-and-hold circuit on the left, unity-gain buffer to minimize drifting in the middle and flash converter on the right. The lack of decoder is intentional as the output needs to be in thermocode. This is an exercise given as part of introduction to ADCs and all parameters must comply with the pre-defined values given in the assignment, so I am not looking for a way to modify the circuit but rather understand its behavior.

[image]
[image]

My understanding is without the capacitor, when the control clock is 0, the output of the source should also be 0. So basically the blue Vcap signal should be flipped vertically, but I do not understand why is it the way that it is now. And when the hold capacitor is added, the sampled signal should retain the voltage value bridging the gap between individual samples, but this also not happen. I expect instead of dipping to 0 V, the shape to be like staircase or step-wise increase. In short, why flipped graph and why no bridging between samples. Visually what I expect to see:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What model do you use for your OPAMP? Is not it curious that Vin stays at 5.5 V instead of showing a waveform similar to Vcap? Have you checked the current flows (between fet and OPAMP etc)?